# Здравствуйте, начал изучать c#. Столкнутся с ошибкой cs0165

Tags: c#

```
double x;
           Console.Write("Введите номер абонента-");
           Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
           switch (x) {
            case +996700:
            Console.Write("-Tend");
            break;
            case +996555:
            Console.Write("-Mega");
            break;
            case +996777:
            Console.Write("-Bell");
            break;
           }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```